# Are there many hyperbolic structures on $ I \times$ Torus?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, low-dimensional-topology

I have a basic question on Thurston's hyperbolization in the (probably too simple) case of $M=[0,1] \times T$ where $T$ is a torus. According to [Thurston](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1982-06-03/S0273-0979-1982-15003-0/S0273-0979-1982-15003-0.pdf) on page 359, M has no hyperbolic structure of finite volume. However

1. The metric $ds^2=dt^2 + e^{2t} |dz^2|$ has negative curvature ($R=-6$) and finite volume. What am I not thinking right here?
2. Is there a unique infinite-volume hyperbolic structure on M? If not, is there a parameterization of these hyperbolic structures?

I have also seen in Marden's book Hyperbolic Manifolds the same statement as that of Thurston.

Any comment is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Well, as for question 1 the metric is not complete and I believe that when mathematicians talk about "hyperbolic structure" they ask for a complete metric. Also, if one allows $t \rightarrow -\infty$ the metric acquires a singularity. However I would not mind if someone with knowledge about this topic can confirm/clarify these additional observations.

Comment: If you want an incomplete metric, then start with a hyperbolic cusped manifold with finite volume. Then its cusps buondaries look like copies of $T^2\times (0,\infty)$. Chop off one of this from the manifold and consider the induced metric here. (which is of course not complete).

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee: of course, $PSL(2,C)$ contains discrete subgroups isomorphic to $Z^2$. (Hint: Do not look for a hyperbolic axis are there is none.)

Comment: @MoisheCohen I agree I wrote wrong. What I meant to say is following... if it has a $Z^2$  sub group, then it consists of parabolic element fixing the same point at infinity. From here we can show that a closed hyperbolic manifold cannot have a $Z^2$ subgroup.

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee: Right.

Comment: You did not read Thurston's statement close enough, he refers to the **interior** $T^2\times (0,1)$ of $M$ not admitting a complete hyperbolic metric of finite volume. Your metric will be either incomplete or of infinite volume, depending on the details that you did not spell out. As for complete hyperbolic metrics on $T^2\times (0,1)$: There is a continuum of those, up to isometry.

Comment: @MoisheCohen You are right. I am interested in  hyperbolic metrics on M, not only in its interior, modulo diffeomorphisms that are homotopic to the identitiy at the boundary of M. If they are not complete is ok.

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Then you should revise your question. At the moment I do not understand what it is.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that if you allow compact Riemannian manifolds with boundary and do not impose any boundary value conditions, then on a compact $n$-ball you have continuum of pairwise nonisometric hyperbolic metrics. This is something that people like to avoid.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Ok. Thanks. I will think how to rephrase the question in order to be more clear and precise.